# Google App Engine link redirection

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect

In my application, I have a form, and when I submit the entered data, the page should be redirected to another link, which has it's own handler.

Here's the python code for the same:

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
from google.appengine.ext import db
import urllib2
import re

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("formrss.html")
    def post(self):
        x = self.request.get("rssquery")
        if x:
            self.redirect("/extract")  

class ExtractFeeds(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("ok")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/extract', ExtractFeeds)], debug=True)
```

formrss.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Live Quora Feed</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Search:<input type = "text" name = "rssquery"><br>
        <input type = "submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when I submit the form data, instead of redirecting to the /extract link and displaying 'ok', the form page gets reloaded and the url is of the form '/?rssquery=(entered_data)'.

I can't seem to figure out what the problem could be here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using post on your form!

```
<form method="POST">
        Search:<input type = "text" name = "rssquery"><br>
        <input type = "submit">
    </form>
```

This handler

```
def post(self):
        x = self.request.get("rssquery")
        if x:
            self.redirect("/extract")
```

is bound to the post and with no post happening it was running the GET

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi how many questions have I done as well, just missing stuff out of fear that I don't understand something correctly. You are welcome.